# staking with wallet adapter failes

Tags: stake

I am using a wallet adapter to sign 2 tx:

1. create a stake account
2. delegate

in a single wallet approval.
and for some reason the tx failed with the following err:

```
Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: incorrect program id for instruction
```

the code split to 4 functions

1. create delegate ACC and instructions
2. prep for balance verify
3. verify balance
4. submit tx

it looks like this:

```
public async verifyBalance(lamportToSend: number, walletPubkey: PublicKey, transaction: Transaction) {
const balance = await this.solanaUtilsService.connection.getBalance(walletPubkey);
const txFee = (await this.solanaUtilsService.connection.getFeeForMessage(
  transaction.compileMessage(),
  'confirmed',
)).value;
const balanceCheck = lamportToSend < balance + txFee ? true : false;
if (!balanceCheck) {
  this._formatErrors({ message: 'not enogh balance' })
  // throw new Error('not enogh balance')
  return false;
}
 return balanceCheck
}

private async prepTx(lamports, tx, walletOwnerPk: PublicKey) {
// verify tx fee
const { blockhash } = await this.solanaUtilsService.connection.getLatestBlockhash();
const txVerify = new Transaction().add(tx)
txVerify.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
txVerify.feePayer = walletOwnerPk

const hasBalance = await this.verifyBalance(lamports, walletOwnerPk, txVerify)
if (hasBalance) {
  return true
} else {
  return false
}
```

}

```
public async delegate(lamportsToDelegate: number, walletOwnerPk: PublicKey, validatorVoteKey: string) {
const createStakeAccount = async (lamportToSend: number, stakeAccountOwner: PublicKey) => {
  const minimumAmount = await this.solanaUtilsService.connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(
    StakeProgram.space,
  );
  const fromPubkey = stakeAccountOwner;
  const newStakeAccount = new Keypair();
  const authorizedPubkey = stakeAccountOwner;
  const authorized = new Authorized(authorizedPubkey, authorizedPubkey);
  const lockup = new Lockup(0, 0, fromPubkey);
  const lamports = minimumAmount + lamportToSend;
  const stakeAccountIns: CreateStakeAccountParams = {
    fromPubkey,
    stakePubkey: newStakeAccount.publicKey,
    authorized,
    lockup,
    lamports
  }
  const newStakeAccountIns = StakeProgram.createAccount(stakeAccountIns)
  return { newStakeAccountIns, newStakeAccount }
}
try {
  const stakeAccountData = await createStakeAccount(lamportsToDelegate, walletOwnerPk)
  const stakeAcc: Keypair = stakeAccountData.newStakeAccount;
  const instruction: DelegateStakeParams = {
    stakePubkey: stakeAcc.publicKey,
    authorizedPubkey: walletOwnerPk,
    votePubkey: new PublicKey(validatorVoteKey)
  }
  const stakeAccIns: Transaction = stakeAccountData.newStakeAccountIns;
  const delegateTX: Transaction = StakeProgram.delegate(instruction);

  const stake: Transaction[] = [stakeAccIns, delegateTX]
  const validTx = await this.prepTx(lamportsToDelegate,delegateTX, walletOwnerPk)


  if (validTx) {
    this.sendTx(stake, walletOwnerPk, [stakeAcc])
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

}

```
private async sendTx(txParam: TransactionInstruction[] | Transaction[], walletPk: PublicKey, extraSigners?: Keypair[]) {
try {
  const { lastValidBlockHeight, blockhash } = await this.solanaUtilsService.connection.getLatestBlockhash();
  const txArgs: TransactionBlockhashCtor = { feePayer: walletPk, blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight: lastValidBlockHeight }
  let transaction: Transaction = new Transaction(txArgs).add(...txParam);
  // this._walletStore.signTransaction(transaction);
  this._walletStore.signTransaction(transaction).subscribe({
    next: async (res: Transaction) => {

      if (extraSigners) transaction.partialSign(...extraSigners);

      //LMT: check null signatures
      for (let i = 0; i < transaction.signatures.length; i++) {
        if (!transaction.signatures[i].signature) {
          throw Error(`missing signature for ${transaction.signatures[i].publicKey.toString()}. Check .isSigner=true in tx accounts`)
        }
      }

      const rawTransaction = transaction.serialize({ requireAllSignatures: false });
      const signature = await this.solanaUtilsService.connection.sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction);
      console.log('https://solscan.io/tx/' + signature)
      const txSend: toastData = {
        message: 'transaction subbmitted',
        icon: 'information-circle-outline',
        segmentClass: "toastInfo"
      }
      this.toasterService.msg.next(txSend)
      const config: BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy = {
        signature, blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight: res.lastValidBlockHeight//.lastValidBlockHeight
      }
      await this.solanaUtilsService.connection.confirmTransaction(config) //.confirmTransaction(txid, 'confirmed');
      const txCompleted: toastData = {
        message: 'transaction completed',
        icon: 'information-circle-outline',
        segmentClass: "toastInfo"
      }
      this.toasterService.msg.next(txCompleted)
    },
    error: (err) => {
      this._formatErrors(err)
    },
  })

} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
  // onMsg('transaction failed', 'error')
}
```

}

any ideas where it can fail?

Comment: According to your error, StakeProgram has an incorrect program id? What stake program is this, and is it deployed on the cluster you're connected to?

Comment: i am connecting to testnet, and as you can see the stakeprogram id is settled automatically by the web3 package.

Comment: seems like the issue not occur on mainnet

Comment: ah, thought so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your error:

> Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: incorrect program id for instruction

The `program_id` for the StakeProgram doesn't match a program deployed on the cluster you're connecting to.

Try search for the program using an explorer to see if it exists on the cluster.

`https://explorer.solana.com/address/<program_id>?cluster=testnet`

Change `testnet` for the cluster you're connected to

Comment: Apparently, I used the vote key from different cluster @_@...
thx!

Comment: done :), just pointing out again thats the validator key wasn’t valid, and not the program id(which is stake111111111111111111111111111ish... program for both mb and testnet)